# Updates are available. Save your document to refresh this area

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-10, microsoft-word-2013, onedrive

We're running MS Office 2013 on Windows 10. We've saved a document in OneDrive and have multiple people editing it. In one paragraph, there is a little icon which has this tool tip:

> Updates are available. Save your document to refresh this area.

Seeing that, I saved my document, though nothing relevant has changed. The little icon is still there and no updates have occurred. How can I view the updates?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to a user using SharePoint 2013 (so it may not be applicable), but what I did was to:

- Use Task Manager to stop `GROOVE.EXE` (OneDrive for Business) and `MSOSYNC.EXE` (Microsoft Office Document Cache) NOTE: Also kill `MSOUC.EXE` (Microsoft Office Upload Center) if it is running.
- Open Explorer, and type `%APPDATA%` in the address bar, then hit Enter
- Move up to the root of AppData, then open `Local->Microsoft->Office->15.0` (so that you are in `c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0` assuming `c:` is the drive your USERS folder is stored)
- Delete the contents of the OfficeFileCache and the WebServiceCache folders (They will be repopulated)
- Open IE, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and delete the contents of the 'Temporary Internet files and website files' cache
- Open the document again

The document then opened properly from the server, and the "Updates are available. Save your document to refresh this area" message was gone.